# 'zip' in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I'm just wondering if there is a ready implementation of zip-function in the standart erlang library.  Something like that:

```
zip([H1|T1], [H2|T2], Acc)->
    zip(T1, T2, Acc ++ [{H1, H2}]);
zip([], [], Acc) ->
    Acc.
```

Comment: I am not at home with Erlang's syntax, but isn't your implementation reversing the order of the lists?

Comment: No. Zip gets the two lists and create new list.  For example, if we have the two lists: A=[a1,a2,a3] and B=[b1,b2,b3], zip create a new list = [a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3].

Comment: I know what zip does, but isn't your example generating `[{a3,b3},{a2,b2},{a1,b1}]` instead? (Again, I'm not versed in Erlang, only Haskell)

Comment: Using `++` in this way is also very inefficient.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a [zip function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#zip-2) in the lists module:

```
> lists:zip([a,b,c], [1,2,3]).
[{a,1},{b,2},{c,3}]
```